# Reordering data frame using factor vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that includes species names. I want to rearrange them in a particular order. To do this I have converted the TAXON vector (character) into a factor. I have then rearranged the levels using the factor() function. Then I have sorted using order(). Is there a way to do this using Tidyverse? I have tried but am running into problems. Some help would be appreciated. Below is the code.

```
fauna.I <- bone.I %>% full_join(mdmx.I, by="TAXON") %>% full_join(teeth.I, by="TAXON") %>% 
          filter(TAXON != "carnivore_large"& TAXON !="carnivore_medium"& TAXON!="carnivore_small" & TAXON!="carnivore_unknown" &
           TAXON!="mammal_unknown" & TAXON!="ungulate_large" & TAXON!="ungulate_medium_large"& TAXON !="ungulate_small_medium"&
           TAXON!="ungulate_small" & TAXON != "unidentified") %>% 
          replace_na(list(bone=0,mdmx=0,teeth=0))%>% rowwise() %>% 
          mutate(TOTAL.I=sum(c(bone,mdmx,teeth))) %>% select(TAXON,TOTAL.I)%>%
          mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% mutate(pctNISP=TOTAL.I/sum(fauna.I$TOTAL.I)*100)

fauna.I$TAXON <- factor(fauna.I$TAXON, 
                 levels=c("bird_unknown","fish_unknown","Leporid_sp.","Panthera_leo_spelaeus","Panthera_pardus", "Canis_lupus", "Canis_sp.", "Vulpes_vulpes", "Crocuta_spelaea", "Hyaena_sp.", "Ursus_spelaeus", "Ursus_arctos", "Ursus_sp.","Rhino_sp.","Equus_ferus","Equus_hydruntinus","Equid_sp.","Megaloceros_giganteus", "Cervus_elaphus",
                 "Dama_dama","Capreolus_capreolus","Cervid_sp.","Bos_primigenius","Bison_priscus","Bos_Bison_sp.","Capra_ibex","Capra_caucasica","Rupicapra_rupicapra","Capra_sp.","Sus_scrofa"))

fauna.I <- fauna.I[order(fauna.I$TAXON),]
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr/tidyverse, to sort a data frame you use `arrange`.

Next, to order by some ordering that is not numerical nor alphabetical, you need to add that ordering to the data frame.
That's kinda what you've done with the factor, but not as transparently as a function like "arrange-by-factor-levels".

First off, factors are really integer vectors with labels. In you case, first level is "bird_unkown", second "fish_unknown", etc. Try this line:

```
str(fauna.I$TAXON)
```

You see, it's integers with labels. So let's add those integers, they are basically your ordering:

```
fauna.I %>% mutate(order=as.integer(TAXON)) %>%
  arrange(order)
```

Also, what's wrong with what you did? Does `order` use the labels?